# problem with the product's display in my cart

Tags: javascript, html, css, product, cart

I try to display all products in localstorage to my cart's page but only the first element is correctly built (everything is ok in localstorage).
I use javascript:

```
for(produit = 0; produit < produitLocalStorage.length; produit++){
        let fullCartTemplate = document.querySelector('#template_full_card');
        newNodeFullCart = document.importNode(fullCartTemplate.content, true);
        document.querySelector('#basket_container').appendChild(newNodeFullCart);
        
        document.querySelector('#name').textContent = `${produitLocalStorage[produit].name}`;
        document.querySelector('#reference').textContent = `Réf : ${produitLocalStorage[produit]._id}`;
        document.querySelector('#price').textContent = `${produitLocalStorage[produit].quantity} x ${produitLocalStorage[produit].price},00€`;
        document.querySelector('#total_price_product').textContent = `${produitLocalStorage[produit].price*produitLocalStorage[produit].quantity},00€`;
        document.querySelector('#number').setAttribute('value', `${produitLocalStorage[produit].quantity}`);
        document.querySelector('#picture_product').setAttribute('src', `${produitLocalStorage[produit].image}`);
```

my template in html code :

```
<template id="template_full_card">
                <div id="recapitulatif_order">
                    <div class="product_card">
                        <img id="picture_product" src="" alt="photo produit">
                        <div id="name_reference">
                            <span id="name"></span>
                            <span id="reference"></span>
                        </div>
                        <input id="number" type="number" value="" min="" max="">
                        <div id="price_trash">
                            <span id = "price"></span>
                            <span id="total_price_product"></span>
                            <span id="trash_logo">
                                <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
</template>
```

I have the structure of each element but not variable's value.
I try to change my id in class but nothing changes

Comment: What do you actually want your question is not quite understandable.!! Be clear before posting here.

Comment: textContent add in tag don't appear in my cart'page except for the first element in of the loop

Comment: I forgot to say this code js is in a loop :

Comment: for(produit = 0; produit < produitLocalStorage.length; produit++){}